# Android Jetpack Compose: How to react to the state changes of 3rd party composable from library (Compose Calendar by boguszpawlowski)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I investigate boguszpawlowski Compose Calendar and I cannot find a way to track state changes of the component, because there are no callback for it.
For example I need to get events only for current month (send a request) and after it I should show them in calendar. When user switch month I should send a request again.
Author in description suggest using state hoisting for it.

> In case you need to react to the state changes, or change the state from the outside of the composable, you need to hoist the state out of the Calendar composable:

```
  @Composable
  fun MainScreen() {
    val calendarState = rememberCalendarState()
    StaticCalendar(calendarState = calendarState)
   
    // now you can manipulate the state from scope of this composable
    calendarState.monthState.currentMonth = MonthYear.of(2020, 5)
  }
```

I understand how to change current of initial month, but I do not know how to listen event when user swipe calendar or click the button to change month.
How can I do it?

[boguszpawlowski ComposeCalendar github link](https://github.com/boguszpawlowski/ComposeCalendar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can listen to state changes using **LaunchedEffect**
i have not used your library but you can pass it to LaunchedEffect

```
LaunchedEffect(calendarState){
// your conditions
// do your api call here
}
```

or

```
LaunchedEffect(calendarState.monthState.currentMonth){
// do your api call here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calendar composable holds its state as an `CalendarState`.
As the selection state is represented by an interface, you can provide your own implementation or you can use the default implementation (`DynamicSelectionState`).

Something like:

```
    val calendarState = rememberSelectableCalendarState()
    SelectableCalendar(calendarState = calendarState)

    Text(
        text = "Selection: ${calendarState.selectionState.selection.joinToString { it.toString() }}",
    )
```

You can use a side effect to know when the current month changes:

```
    LaunchedEffect(calendarState.monthState.currentMonth){
        Log.d("Calendar",calendarState.monthState.currentMonth.toString())
    }
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but nothing I can do with month changes, because there is a callback in selectable date:  val state = rememberSelectableCalendarState(
    confirmSelectionChange = { viewModel.onSelectionChanged(it); true },
    initialSelectionMode = Period,
  )

Comment: @MyFoenix Just use a side effect like `LaunchedEffect(calendarState.monthState.currentMonth)` to listen the change of the current month